# OneToMany relationship: referenced id null

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, one-to-many

I'am trying to persist two entities that have OneToMany relationship 
 the header of my two entities are:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Customer customer;

/******
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "customer")
private List<Data> datas;
```

in both entities manager i've created 2 method that allow to create nd persist the two entities.

```
 public Data createData(String name, int number) {
        Data d = new Data();
        data.setNamte(name);
        data.setNumber(number);
        return mail;
    }

 public Customer createCustomer(String name, String famillyname, int age, List<Data> datas) {
        Customer cust=new Customer();  
       cust.setName(name);
       cust.setFamillyName(famillyname);
       cust.setAge(age);
       cust.setData(data);
       em.persist(cust)
        return data;
    }
```

When i called both methods the entities were successfully created and persisted except the customer id in the data datatable which get  
Where do You think the problem consists in?

Comment: Are you setting the Customer to the Data.customer?  What does cust.setData(data) do?

Comment: Setting the data to the customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner side of the association is `Data.customer`. JPA doesn't care about the inverse side (`Customer.datas`), but this is the only side you initialize.

Call `data.setCustomer(cust)` on every Data that you want to associate with the customer.